# Does the question "how long do you sleep" sound natural?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is *how long do you sleep* something a native English speake would say if the want to know how many hours some sleeps per night? For example:

> Person A: how long do you sleep?
>
> Person B: I sleep for 8 hours.

Would

> How many hours do you sleep

sound better?

I am pretty sure the first question is grammatically correct, but I have doubts as to whether it sound natural. If it doesn't sound natural, then what would  a antive English speaker say instead?

Comment: What would be the alternatives for this if it wasn't natural, please mention it in your question.

Comment: Assuming the exchange is part of a conversation and not a question A has suddenly asked, "How long do you sleep for?" is probably more idiomatic. "How many hours do you sleep [at night]?" would be fine too.

Comment: Yes, in the right context it would work well, but in others it wouldn’t. Here I’d expect a context like this to make it work in conversation -  B: “I am generally a very sound sleeper and rarely wake up during the night.”  A: “How long do you sleep?”  B:  “Eight hours.”

Comment: Let's say I am just curious to know know how long does someone sleeps for would "how long do you sleep for" sound natural?